# Encoding and an Emacs file

Tags: emacs, encoding

The code in http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/ssft18/lec1/Prelude.agda gives rise to an encoding problem. For example â†’ should be displayed →. Another example is â„•, which should appear as ℕ.

I took the code from the website above and pasted it into an Emacs file.

I think the character change I need to carry out is from "Western" to "Unicode".

Is there an automatic way I can correct all of these mistakes in the website above?

Ideally it would be something I could do in my Emacs file, but if this is not possible it would still be really useful to know a way of making the conversion.

I have tried to apply some of the suggestions on the following website
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34585/how-convert-txt-file-to-utf-8-from-windows-1251
but they don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that browser is not opening it as a UTF-8 file when it is. Just download the file instead of copy and paste (or change the encoding the browser uses before you do).